# Access SQL error

Tags: sql, ms-access

When I try to access a database for my access form, I keep getting the same error message;

> Invalid bracketing of name Forms![Meter Reading Date > Box].tbxCurrent]

I've tried removing, and adding brackets and replaced them with `'` but have had no luck.

```
SELECT 0.3 AS CurrWaterRate, 
       forms![Meter Reading Date Box].tbxNewGasRate AS CurrGasRate, 
       forms![Meter Reading Date Box].tbxNewElecRate AS CurrElecRate,
       4.65 AS BaseElec, 
       IIf([RV]=True,0,3) AS BaseGas, 
       IIf([RV]=True,0,9) AS Sewer, 
       IIf([RV]=True,0,13.35) AS Garbage, 
       [Current Month Utilities].*, 
       [Previous Month Utilities].*, 
       [Current Month Utilities]!KWHReading-
            [Previous Month Utilities]!KWHReading AS BillKWH, 
       [Current Month Utilities]!GasReading-
            [Previous Month Utilities]!GasReading AS BillGas, 
       [Current Month Utilities]!WaterReading-
            [Previous Month Utilities]!WaterReading AS BillWater,
       [Customer Maintenance].*, 
       ([BillKWH]*[CurrElecRate]) AS DueKWH, 
       IIf([RV]=True,0, 
           IIf([Electric]=True,0, 
                IIf([BillGas]>10,6.5+([BillGas]-
                     10)*[CurrGasRate],6.5))) AS DueGas, 
       IIf([RV]=True,0,
           IIf([BillWater]<3,8,([BillWater]-3)*0.3+8)) AS DueWat, 
       IIf([RV]=True,0,
           IIf([Electric]=True,0,3)) AS GasSurcharge, 
       (([DueWat]+[DueKWH]+[DueGas]+[GasSurcharge]+[Sewer]+
         [Garbage]+[BaseElec]+[BaseGas])*0.0825) AS Taxable, 
       [LotRent]+[TrailRent]+[DueWat]+[DueKWH]+[DueGas]+
       [GasSurcharge]+[Garbage]+[Sewer]+[Taxable]+[BaseElec]+
       [LateFee] AS TotalDue, 
       ([TotalDue]+[PastDue]-[Credit]) AS GrandTotal, 
       [FName] & " " & [LName] AS Name
FROM ([Customer Maintenance] 
INNER JOIN [Current Month Utilities] 
    ON [Customer Maintenance].AccountNo=[Current Month Utilities].AccountNo) 
INNER JOIN [Previous Month Utilities] 
    ON [Customer Maintenance].AccountNo=[Previous Month Utilities].AccountNo;
```

Comment: try this `forms![Meter Reading Date Box]!tbxNewGasRate`

Comment: Please re-check error and posted SQL. That parameter, *tbxCurrent* does not show in query.

Comment: You're likely querying off other queries, and the error is in one of these other ones